# Как происходит подгрузка css при загрузке страницы?

Tags: css, apache

Вопрос скорее теоретический. Я пишу сайт и хочу сделать так чтобы одна часть сайта была оформлена "по минимуму", а другая отображала сайт во всей красе - но все стили я храню всего в двух файлах `positioning.css` для позиционирования элементов на странице, и `style.css` для "разукрашивания" html элементов.

В случае если мне нужна версия "во всей красе" - то тут все понятно, итак будут загружаться полностью оба файла.

Но иногда мне нужна пользоваться той частью сайта которая почти не стилизована (т.е. у нее тоже есть css свойства, их очень мало, но она располагаются в тех же файлах что и для загрузки обычной версии) - как в этом случае будут загружаться свойства? Загрузятся css файлы с нужными И НЕ НУЖНЫМИ свойствами?

Или же веб-сервер сам отсортирует неиспользуемые css свойства и подгрузит только то что действительно необходимо???

P.S. можно конечно разделить свойства для каждой из версий свои файлы, но суть вопроса в том чтобы понимать как это работает

Comment: ```подгрузит только то что действительно необходимо???``` - нет, все данные будут у клиента если файл присутствует в заголовках.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я правильно понял что если условно файл будет весить 10мб то он отправит для минимальной версии все эти 10 мб?

Comment: Да, именно так, если файл весит 10мб(размер собсно не важен, важно что это статичный контент) - клиент скачает этот файл **единожды** при верной настройке сервера (кэш на стороне клиента)